# wifi dongle is not supported by Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

how to configure the wifi dongle chipset: RTL8188EUS , so that it could be supported by Raspbian?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a driver to support that chip.  My general advice is to avoid Realtek based devices with linux and particularly the pi; unfortunately this covers a large share of the wifi market.

There are two Realtek drivers included with Raspbian; you can try them in order and check to see if an interface gets added:

```
sudo modprobe 8192cu
sudo ip link
```

If you see a listing for `wlan0` you have a chance.  Otherwise:

```
sudo rmmod 8192cu
sudo modprobe rtl8187
sudo ip link
```

Again, if you see `wlan0` you have a chance; if not that is the end of the line possibilities wise.

Answer (score 0):

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

I had the exact same problem with the exact model of Wifi dongle.
Here is the answer i have submitted to multiple similar questions and guaranteed to help you fix your problem.

The best and easiest way to handle this problem is as following
(This is similar to the question posted here[[How do I install the drivers for a WiFi dongle with the RealTek 8812AU chipset on Raspbian?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/67719/76125]))

1. sudo wget http://www.fars-robotics.net/install-wifi -O /usr/bin/install-wifi

   - Downloads the installation file
2. sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/install-wifi

   - makes it executable
3. Installation process

   - sudo install-wifi -c rpi-update
          - check for driver if rpi-update is run.
   - sudo rpi-update
         - if a driver is available you can run rpi-update to update firmware.
   - sudo install-wifi -u rpi-update
         - then update the driver for the new kernel installed by rpi-update.
   - sudo reboot
         - now reboot to update the kernel with the new wifi driver.

Comment: Please stop posting identical ([first](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75108/34558), [second](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75109/34558), this one is third) answers to multiple questions. Instead please answer once and mark the other questions as duplicates.